# Newsletter signup not showing on one page checkout

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout

We are using the one page checkout on a customer site, but it's not showing the "click here to subscribe to newsletter" checkbox, which is a standard option in Magento themes.

Does anybody know how to enable that?

[image: Checkout Screenshot]

Comment: When you disable third-party extensions and switch back to the default Themen do you see the subscribe link?

Comment: In default theme there is no newsletter subscription option in checkout page

Answer (score 2):

In checkout page, there is no option for newsletter subscription by default (as per `base/default` theme).

If you check the default theme, you can see that, one page checkout page do not possess `left` block.It only possess `content` and `right` blocks. Content block is used to show different steps in checkout and right section contains a breif view of checkout steps.

Suppose you need to add newsletter subscription in your theme, then you can follow these steps.

1. Create a `local.xml` file in your theme.
2. Put this content inside it.

   File : `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/layout/local.xml`

   ```
   <layout>
            <checkout_onepage_index>
                <reference name="right">
                <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="newsletter" as="newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml" before="-" />
                </reference>
            </checkout_onepage_index>
    </layout>
   ```

[*This answer is a part of #mageStackDay. It is an event conducted by Magento Community members as part of increasing the question-answer ratio. For more information http://www.magestackday.com/*]